# How To Enable Assembly Redirects For Nuget Package

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nuget, vstest

I have a solution that contains these Projects:

- A
- A.Test
- SharedTestBase

`SharedTestBase` References `A` via a NuGet Package.  `A.Test` directly references `A` and `SharedTestBase`.

The latest nuget pushed version of `A` is 1.1, which is referenced by `SharedTestBase`.  I've made changes to `A` and now `A` is 1.2 locally, which is what `A.Test` references.

So now when I run a test in `A.Test`, it fails with a message that it can't find `A.1.1`.

I want to be able to test `A's` code, before I create a nuget package for it.  How do I handle allowing calls from `SharedTestBase` to use the local version of `A` instead of it's NuGet version?

I can add a `<Configuration><runtime><assemblyBinding><dependentAssembly>` attribute, but I'd have to add it every single time I build a new version of `A`, yuck!

Comment: Is it a case that you don't want to push 1.2 to NuGet without testing it? 
If so you can use a local version of it for testing by configuring NuGet Package Sources.

Comment: Yes.Do you have a link for Configuring NuGet Package Sources?

Comment: Sure, will add an answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a local Package Source. Once you've got it added, drop your 1.2 .nupkg file into the folder you've selected, and then your other project should be able to find it. More info can be found on nuget.org

https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#creating-local-feeds

[image: Package Manager Settings] 
[image: Package sources]

Comment: So Update `ShareTestBase` to get the package from the local folder?  This allows that code to work, but I can still have a project reference to `A` from `A.Test`?